# WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.ror in / application

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-7.5, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have configured a local website on my machine which has a virtual directory for allowing file downloads. The files are downloading perfectly with no issues but with GET requests.

The problem is I want to use POST request to download because I want to include some request parameters. But whenever I try to download a file using POST it throws WebException.

Here is my C# code to download request.

```
request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create (remoteFile);
request.Timeout = 300; 
request.AddRange(0, (int) fileLength - 1);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.GetResponse ();
```

I searched through many threads. I tried enabling directory browsing, adding POST verbs in request filtering, adding verb to the handler Mapping. But had no success.

Please help me to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have not set the permissions on the folder. Try allowing Everyone to have access to the folder you are using, with read and write enabled.